# GET to NGINX reverse proxy works but POST gives me a 502 Bad Gateway Response

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, curl

I am using NGINX as a reverse proxy and just put up a new service written in Go.

The service has two endpoints

```
GET /tracking/ping

POST /tracking/customer
```

In NGINX, I am using the following to proxy the request

```
location /v1/location/ {
    proxy_pass http://path-to-tracking-service:8181/;
}
```

When `curl` the two endpoints such as the following, I get different results.

The `GET /tracking/ping` endpoint

```
curl -X GET https://example.com/v1/location/tracking/ping
"Pong!"
```

The 'POST /tracking/customer` endpoint

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"userId":"1234"}'  https://example.com/v1/location/tracking/customer
<html>
<head><title>502 Bad Gateway</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>502 Bad Gateway</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.9.12</center>
</body>
```

Not sure why this would happen. I am proxying other services I have and `POST` requests work perfectly fine.

Here is the `nginx.conf`

user  nginx;
    worker_processes  1;

```
error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                    '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                    '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    proxy_connect_timeout       600;
proxy_send_timeout          600;
proxy_read_timeout          600;
send_timeout                600;

    #gzip  on;

    #include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    #server {
        #include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
    #}

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name *.example.com;
        #return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
    }

    server {


    #listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name *.example.com;

    ssl_certificate           /etc/ssl/example.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key       /etc/ssl/example.key;

    #ssl on;
    ssl_session_cache  builtin:1000  shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_protocols  TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!CAMELLIA:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
    }
}
```

I have separate files that are being linked to `/sites-enabled` that include my `proxy_params` declarations.

Two of them are the following

```
location /v1/location/ {
    proxy_pass http://example.com:8181/;
}

location /v1/ {
    proxy_pass http://example.com:8282/;
}
```

I could see their maybe being an issue with it getting confused by the `/v1` on both the proxies, but it works for the `GET` endpoint.

***EDIT***

Some people have brought up the point that it may be panicking so I checked the docker logs for the go container and got the following

```
location-tracking-staging-1 | 2016-03-14T02:35:33.580963673Z 2016/03/14 02:35:33 http: panic serving 10.7.1.5:35613: no reachable servers
location-tracking-staging-1 | 2016-03-14T02:35:33.581005488Z goroutine 97 [running]:
location-tracking-staging-1 | 2016-03-14T02:35:33.581012905Z net/http.(*conn).serve.func1(0xc820057b00)
location-tracking-staging-1 | 2016-03-14T02:35:33.581017348Z    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:1389 +0xc1
location-tracking-staging-1 | 2016-03-14T02:35:33.581030498Z panic(0x81e620, 0xc82013c5e0)
location-tracking-staging-1 | 2016-03-14T02:35:33.581034545Z    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:426 +0x4e9
location-tracking-staging-1 | 2016-03-14T02:35:33.581038792Z main.RepoCreateVendorLocation(0xc82011ecb8, 0x4, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, ...)
location-tracking-staging-1 | 2016-03-14T02:35:33.581042502Z    /go/src/location-tracking/repo.go:19 +0x178
location-tracking-staging-1 | 2016-03-14T02:35:33.581047145Z main.VendorLocationCreate(0x7f8a4366d978, 0xc8200c2ea0, 0xc820119260)
location-tracking-staging-1 | 2016-03-14T02:35:33.581050747Z    /go/src/location-tracking/handlers.go:63 +0x47b
location-tracking-staging-1 | 2016-03-14T02:35:33.581054911Z net/http.HandlerFunc.ServeHTTP(0x9965b0, 0x7f8a4366d978, 0xc8200c2ea0, 0xc820119260)
location-tracking-staging-1 | 2016-03-14T02:35:33.581058786Z    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:1618 +0x3a
location-tracking-staging-1 | 2016-03-14T02:35:33.581062770Z github.com/gorilla/mux.(*Router).ServeHTTP(0xc820010640, 0x7f8a4366d978, 0xc8200c2ea0, 0xc820119260)
location-tracking-staging-1 | 2016-03-14T02:35:33.581066604Z    /go/src/github.com/gorilla/mux/mux.go:103 +0x270
location-tracking-staging-1 | 2016-03-14T02:35:33.581070176Z net/http.serverHandler.ServeHTTP(0xc820056300, 0x7f8a4366d978, 0xc8200c2ea0, 0xc820119260)
location-tracking-staging-1 | 2016-03-14T02:35:33.581073992Z    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2081 +0x19e
location-tracking-staging-1 | 2016-03-14T02:35:33.581077629Z net/http.(*conn).serve(0xc820057b00)
location-tracking-staging-1 | 2016-03-14T02:35:33.581081221Z    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:1472 +0xf2e
location-tracking-staging-1 | 2016-03-14T02:35:33.581084811Z created by net/http.(*Server).Serve
location-tracking-staging-1 | 2016-03-14T02:35:33.581088336Z    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2137 +0x44e
```

Comment: Please post your nginx config, especially the relevant location parts.

Comment: @Tim I have updated my post with `nginx.conf` as well as included the proxies defined under `/sites-enabled`

Comment: Did your program panic?

Comment: @MichaelHampton not sure what you mean? As in a Go panic? (I am still very new to Go...)

Comment: Yes, a Go panic. You should take a look and see if it's actually still running...

Comment: As usually with nginx just run debug binary and add debug keyword to a error_log option

Comment: Do you have the "headers more" module compiled in? That lets you add a header to be sure you're hitting the location block you expect. However it seems like you just have a bad proxy_pass in there. Curl the url (port 8xxx) directly from the box and see what happens.

Comment: @Tim if it was a bad proxy, wouldn't I not be able to hit the `GET /ping` endpoint I exposed. I am able to hit this endpoint fine. So the proxy has to be working in some regard

Comment: @MichaelHampton It is still running because I can hit the `GET /ping` endpoint through that proxy.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I edited my POST with some logs that may suggest the program panicked. I don't have much experience in reading Go logs so I can't tell for sure.

Comment: Looks like a panic to me. The big clue is that it tells you "panic"! Time to debug your code.

Comment: Haha, @MichaelHampton it wouldn't be the first time I was told something and the problem ended up being something completely different! I will debug it and post the answer.

Comment: This is **NOT** how to configure nginx using the Debin conf file layout! You should NOT be amending the supplied files in /etc/nginx. You should NOT be using server{..} blocks in /etc/nginx/* (only in /etc/nginx/sites-available then symlinking these in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled).  While it is *likely* that the error is coming from the back end because we can't have any confidence in the integrity of your config, its impossible to say.

Answer (score 0):

My NGINX had similar failure with POST request, while GET request was working fine.

Fix was to add firewall rule to allow HTTP(S) traffic through host machine's firewall.

This might not apply to your particular configuration.

Answer (score -1):

## Plan

- Run https://gist.github.com/bradmontgomery/2219997 as separate process on port 5000
- proxy_pass python http server to https using POST requests

## Problem with "502 Bad Gateway" giving config

- cat /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/example.local

---

```
server {
        location /random {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000;
        }
}
```

---

root@sf:/var/www# curl -d "foo=bar&bin=baz" http://localhost:5000

```
<html><body><h1>hi!</h1></body></html>
```

root@sf:/var/www# curl -d "foo=bar&bin=baz" https://example.local/random

```
<html>
<head><title>502 Bad Gateway</title></head>
....
```

## Solution

- After deep research I found this article and I tried it out:
  http://invalidlogic.com/2011/04/12/serving-static-content-via-post-from-nginx/

### nginx config after changes:

```
server {
...
        error_page 502 =200 @502;

        location /random {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000;
        }


        location @502 {
                root /var/www/sf_random;
                proxy_method GET;
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000;
        }
}
```

- config syntax validation

  nginx -t
- after successful validation

  service nginx restart

## And I got it working :)